# g++ 5.2.1 std::chrono Undeclared

Tags: g++

I am pretty certain this bug should have been solved a long time ago in previous versions of g++, but in my case I still see this when giving the command:

```
std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10))
```

the error message I get is:

```
In member function ‘long long int Iterator::next()’:
error: ‘std::this_thread’ has not been declared
```

Comment: not enough information (command line, system, minimal test program, etc).

Comment: You are correct. This was from command line on Ubuntu 15.10. What do you mean by minimal test program? Should I write a one-liner and produce the output?

Comment: OK, I found the problem. The code (unfortunately not written by me) had a customized thread helper file which was masked as thread. Once I included "thread" in the code then it compiles. Sorry for troubling you.

Answer (score 0):

`std::this_thread` is in `C++11`. Use `-std=c++11` flag.

```
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

int main() {
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
}
```

compile:

```
g++ test.cpp --std=c++11 -g -Wall
```

version:

```
$ g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/5.2.0/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Configured with: /build/gcc/src/gcc-5.2.0/configure --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=https://bugs.archlinux.org/ --enable-languages=c,c++,ada,fortran,go,lto,objc,obj-c++ --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-libmpx --with-system-zlib --with-isl --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-clocale=gnu --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-libssp --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-linker-build-id --enable-lto --enable-plugin --enable-install-libiberty --with-linker-hash-style=gnu --enable-gnu-indirect-function --disable-multilib --disable-werror --enable-checking=release --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=gcc4-compatible
Thread model: posix
gcc version 5.2.0 (GCC)
```

Comment: I did. My flags are '-std=c+11' '-g' and '-Wall'

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the C+11 flag **and** that you include "thread" in your header.